# String from jquery array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking at arrays in jquery and have this issue, I need to assign a key with a town name, but struggling to understand how to deal with the spaces.

```
var hashtable = {};
hashtable['Bognor Regis'] = ["lat=50.782998&lng=-0.673061","Sussex"];
var str = hashtable.Bognor Regis[0];

alert(str);
```

I thought perhaps I could do this

```
hashtable['Bognor-Regis'] = ["lat=50.782998&lng=-0.673061","Sussex"];

var str = hashtable.Bognor-Regis[0];
```

then remove the - later, but it only seems to work if i have something like this

```
hashtable['BognorRegis'] = ["lat=50.782998&lng=-0.673061","Sussex"];
```

What's the correct way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keys have spaces you have to use the array accessor to retrieve them:

```
var hashtable = {};
hashtable['Bognor Regis'] = ["lat=50.782998&lng=-0.673061","Sussex"];
var str = hashtable['Bognor Regis'][0];

alert(str);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/84tGm/)